# How can I sum two numbers in Latex with my own command?

Tags: sum, latex

I have to sum two numbers (integers) in LaTeX. I also have to "print" the process of sum. So it would look like 5+2=7 in text. Any ideas?
My code so far:

```
\newcommand{\Sum}
{\newcounter{cnt}
\setcountter{cnt}{1+1}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem.

```
\newcommand{\Sum} [2] {#1 + #2 = \the\numexpr #1 + #2 \relax \\}
```

And then I use my command as:

```
\Sum {7} {3}
```

Answer (score 13):

In LaTeX, first you have to define a counter with:

```
\newcounter{countername}
```

Then you can put a value in this counter with:

```
\setcounter{countername}{<value>}
```

where `<value>` is an integer. Or you can add one to this counter with:

```
\stepcounter{countername}
```

or you can add some arbitrary value to this counter with:

```
\addtocounter{countername}{<value>}
```

---

Then, to access this counter you use:

```
\value{countername}
```

so you can, for example, make calculations with this counter:

```
\setcounter{anothercounter}{%
  \numexpr\value{countername}+10\relax%
}
```

Then, when you need to print the value of this counter to the pdf file, you can you the mighty `\the`:

```
\the\value{countername}
```

or you can use one of these:

```
\arabic{countername}
\roman{countername}
\Roman{countername}
\alph{countername}
\Alph{countername}
```

Comment: Now I managed to sum numbers but I was not able to display the process of sum. Code: \newcounter{cnt}
\newcounter{lol}
\setcounter{lol}{5}
\newcounter{b}
\setcounter{b}{2}
\setcounter{cnt}{\numexpr lol+b \relax}
\newcommand{\Sestej}{\arabic{cnt}
}

Comment: @FatTommy You cannot use the name of the counter in `\numexpr` like that. The name of the counter is just a symbolic reference to the actual counter. Remember that TeX is a typesetting system, so anything that doesn't have a special meaning (a control sequence, which is prepended with a ``\``, for example) is just printed material. I updated my answer to suit your needs.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps a different syntax can be in order; instead of supplying each argument to calculate a sum, you can supply the operator with the operands. This allows you to be a little more flexible in terms of the input and also provide more functionality:

[image: printed output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\NewDocumentCommand{\showcalculation}{o m}{$
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {#1}{#2} = \fpeval{#2}
  $}

\begin{document}

\showcalculation{7+3}

\showcalculation{1+2-3+4}

\showcalculation[22 \div 7]{22 / 7}

\showcalculation[10 \times 3^{7 - 7}]{10 * 3 ^ (7 - 7)}

\end{document}
```

The optional argument for `\showcalculation` uses a LaTeX formatting for the printable calculation.